# Scientists who became major political leaders

Tags: science, biography

What examples can you find of these? I want the list to include people who satisfy two criteria:
(a) Major political leader = king, president, prime-minister, very senior cabinet minister, mayor of capital, something in this league.
(b) Scientist = someone who has actively worked in science (published papers or books) or at the very least had an impressive career in industrial R&D (with technical accomplishments, not just as a bureuacrat).

One example: [Chaim Weizmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Weizmann). Another, less obvious one which makes the cut nevertheless: [Yury Luzhkov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzhkov)

EDIT: Adding from answers: Angela Merkel, Tony Tan.

Comment: [Angela Merkel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkel) is physical chemist.

Comment: Assembling a list of examples [doesn't really work well with the Q&A format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), I'm afraid I'll have to vote to close. There are quite a few scientists who turned into politics, both China's premier, Wen Jiabao, and China's president, Hu Jintao, have backgrounds in engineering, for example. Angela Merkel has a doctorate in physical chemistry, and if your question includes political scientists then the list goes on ad infinitum.

Comment: Well, I meant to include only exact or natural sciences. So economics, political science, the law, psychology, etc. are not considered relevant (not disrespect implied). Angela Merkel does count.

Comment: Sorry, Yannis is right. Even if you ask about only one specific type of scientist, you are still asking for a list, and not an answer.

Comment: You may find http://www.economist.com/node/13496638 of interest.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has mentioned good old Benjamin Franklin.

Answer (score 0):

[Steven Chu](http://www.biography.com/people/steven-chu-9247820) comes to mind.

Other candidates might include

- [Henry Kissenger](http://www.biography.com/people/henry-kissinger-9366016) - assuming that political science is a science
- [Douglass North](http://www.biography.com/people/douglass-c-north-9425046)
- [Thomas Schelling](http://www.biography.com/people/thomas-crombie-schelling-9473890)
- [Albert Schweitzer](http://www.biography.com/people/albert-schweitzer-9476451) assuming that the UN is government
- [Friedrich von Hayek](http://www2.lse.ac.uk/aboutLSE/keyFacts/nobelPrizeWinners/vonHayek.aspx)
- [Paul Krugman](http://www2.lse.ac.uk/aboutLSE/keyFacts/nobelPrizeWinners/Krugman.aspx)
- [Elsie Widdowson](https://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/712542/Elsie-Widdowson)
- [Hu Jintao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hu_Jintao#Personal_life)
- [Antoine Lavosier](http://humantouchofchemistry.com/antoinelaurent-de-lavoisier.htm)
- [Rush D. Holt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Holt)
- [Jerry McNerney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_McNerney)
- [Vern Ehlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vern_Ehlers)
- [Bill Foster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Foster_%28Illinois_politician%29)
- [Mario Monti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Monti)
- [Lucas Papademos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_Papademos)
- [Tony Tan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Tan_%28Singaporean_president%29)

Comment: Impressive list, but most of the people on it are rather civil servants. Steven Chu is borderline - I guess that his position is also more akin to that of civil servant to that of an elected leader, although formally it makes the cut. Also, I'd like to limit the science part to "hard sciences".

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Papademos was prime minister of Greece for a few months.

Comment: @YannisRizos: But his Ph.D. is in economics.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Yes, I was talking more about the "civil servant" part. Although he wasn't elected as a prime minister, he was appointed in a provisional government, so probably he fails both your criteria.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Provisional government can do, but economics is a sinker...

Comment: Mario Monti isn't a scientist, he's an economist…